# How to properly configure IIS URL Rewrite

Tags: asp.net-core, iis, iis-8

I am running IIS 8.5 on Win 2012 R2. I have a website under which I have hosted multiple .Net Core 3.1 WebAPIs, each running under its own non-managed app pools.

```
wwww.myrootsite.com -> this is site binding on the Website in IIS
|-> API.Employees -> Separate app running on non-managed AppPool1
|-> API.Departments -> Separate app running on non-managed AppPool2
```

Within API.Employees, lets say I have 2 controllers mapping to /api/employees and api/teams.

Currently, for UI, the endpoint looks like this.

```
https://wwww.myrootsite.com/API.Employees/api/employees
https://wwww.myrootsite.com/API.Employees/api/teams
```

I want URLs to look like this.

```
https://wwww.myrootsite.com/api/employees
https://wwww.myrootsite.com/api/teams
```

I already have ARR 3.0 and URL Rewrite 2.0 modules installed on the server.

So I tried creating an inbound rule for api/teams. This is what I have currently configured.

```
<rewrite>
    <rules>
        <rule name="API.Employees.Teams Rewrite" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="^api/teams?(.*)" />
            <action type="Rewrite" url="API.Employees/{R:0}" logRewrittenUrl="true" />
        </rule>
    </rules>
</rewrite>
```

However, when I try to access the URL https://wwww.myrootsite.com/api/teams?id=100, I get 500 internal server error. I am not able to get further details of what is causing the 500 error. Can anyone kindly point out, what am I doing wrong and how do I get further details of the error?

Thanks!

Comment: You can use [failed request tracking](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules) to view detailed error information.

Comment: Thanks. I enabled failed request tracking. I see that the rewrite URL is coming up as https://wwww.myrootsite.com:446/api/teams?id=100 as the port binding on the site is on port 446. However on the port translation is supposed to happen at LTM level as iRules are configured to send myrootsite to the corresponding VM IPs on this port. So next question will be - how do I make sure that rewritten URL does not have the port ?

Comment: It is impossible to remove the port from the url. Unless you hide it using the default port.